# Removing WellPanel using removeUI

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to remove the entire wellpanel using removeUI() in my shiny app. I'm not sure what to be used as a selector. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Can you work a bit on your question so we can help you? What have you tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the UI and then open up a Shiny app in a browser and use **inspect element** you can see that `wellPanel` has a `class = well`

[image: Inspect element]

So one possibility is to specify the `class` a selector like `.class_name`. In your case it is: `selector = ".well"`.

Here is a minimal Shiny app that removes a single `wellPanel` from a page using `class`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    "This is going to be removed",
    plotOutput("plot")
  ),

  actionButton("btn", "Remove wellPanel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(iris))

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    removeUI(selector = ".well")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```